# java beginner- is an arraylist call by reference

Tags: java, arraylist

In a java program, I want 3 arraylist variables to be modified by a call to a single function.

Am I correct in thinking that if I pass these 3 arraylists as parameters to that function, then all 3 can be modified within the function? Or will I have to modify each arraylist in a separate function, and specify that array list as the return value, to ensure that it is modified.

Comment: what is the logical purpose of modifing these lists?

Comment: You could answer this question by writing a program.  It would take less than 5 minutes of your time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Am I correct in thinking that if I pass these 3 arraylists as parameters to that function, then all 3 can be modified within the function?

In a word, yes.

It is worth noting that the "by reference" terminology in the title of your question is not exactly right. In Java, everything is passed *by value*, including object references. It is the fact that the three `ArrayList` parameters are references *themselves* that makes any changes made to the lists propagate back to the caller.

Comment: Additional info: This doesn't mean that Java has call-by-reference :)

Comment: Java is call-by-value, but passes _references_ by value.  This is, in fact, a different thing.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Corrected that, but my point is still valid. No need to ask this question. OP, here's a good quote: _"If the method changes its copy of the pointer to point to a different object the original pointer is not affected. If the method changes some of the attributes of the object, it changes the original object."_ From [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/327166/java/java/call-value-or-call-reference)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can pass the 3 `ArrayList`s as parameters to the method. They are treated like any other object.

As to whether to return another `ArrayList`, this depends a lot on what the method has to do.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works like "call by reference":

```
package arrayList;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CallByValueReference {

class myObject {
    String str;

    public myObject(String str) {
        super();
        this.str = str;
    }

    public String getStr() {
        return str;
    }

    public void setStr(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "myObject [str=" + str + "]";
    }   
}

ArrayList<myObject> strArray = new ArrayList<myObject>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new CallByValueReference().test();
}

private void test() {
    strArray.add(new myObject("entry1") );
    System.out.println(strArray);
    strArray.get(0).setStr("entry2");
    System.out.println(strArray);
}
}
```

The output is:

```
[myObject [str=entry1]]
[myObject [str=entry2]]
```